# Searching for information on Isaiah Gordon of North Carolina

Tags: united-states

I am looking for information on siblings and ancestors of Isaiah Gordon, born in North Carolina in 1802. I have already have U.S. Census info after that date.

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy and Family History SE Bill. It's helpful if you post more information about what you do know about Isaiah Gordon.  For instance, if you know his wife's name, his marriage record might help find siblings and parents.

Comment: Also, I would add, it helps to only look for one thing at a time. Are you looking for a birth certificate? A death certificate? A marriage certificate?

Answer (score 2):

Bill, the best way to find information on siblings and ancestors of Isaiah Gordon, born in North Carolina in 1802 would be going back to the 1st US Census(1790) and the 2nd US Census(1800) of North Carolina. You may not know their names; if this is the case, then you may be able to look at the names of Isaiah Gordon's children in the US Census record you already possess. Comparing the names of his male children to that of the Heads of Household in aforementioned 1790 & 1800 US Census, may lead you to great success due to the fact that many Families then and now named their children after their own ancestors in remembrance of them.

Further as a possible resource: Heads of families at the first census of the United States taken in the year 1790.. Washington, D.C.: Govt. Print Off., 1908.

If you subscribe to ancestry.com you can also view this link below

http://search.ancestry.com/Browse/BookView.aspx?dbid=10170&iid=dvm_PrimSrc000237-00002-0

Heads of Families in North Carolina 1790.

A visit to the Library and Archives in North Carolina would also be beneficial, most of the time brick walls are toppled by the records offline.